# VBA ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, mismatch, byref

Initially in my main code section I had an ugly if statement - though ugly it would run. I decided to make it a function that I would call, this caused me to get an error "**Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch**". My assumption is that the function needs to be referenced properly, though I've been reading the documentation and can't see why >.<

Declaring ShiftValue variable:

`Dim ShiftValue As String

ShiftValue = LCase(Sheets("Raw_Rota").Cells(Counter, "C").Value)`

The function contents and declaration:

```
Function ShiftCompare(ByRef ShiftValue As String)

If StrComp(ShiftValue, "am", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Call IncAMs(AMs)   'this function increments the variable by 1.
        Call Inc(Counter)

    ElseIf StrComp(ShiftValue, "pm", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Call IncPMs(PMs)
        Call Inc(Counter)

    ElseIf StrComp(ShiftValue, "days", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Call IncDays(Days)
        Call Inc(Counter)

    ElseIf StrComp(ShiftValue, "leave", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Call IncLeave(Leave)
        Call Inc(Counter)

    Else 'If the string doesn't compare to the above values tally it as unknown
        Call IncUnknown(Unknown)
        Call Inc(Counter)
    End If
End Function
```

Update:

My function call is in the Else part of an If section like so:

```
If X
"'Do stuff..."

Else 

Call ShiftCompare(ShiftValue)

EndIf
```

The error is raised on the Function line:

`Function ShiftCompare(ByVal ShiftValue As String)`

The value in whatever cell being referenced is either empty or a string.

Comment: Do you need it to be `ByRef`? It doesnt look like you are using it to return anything to the calling function, so try using `ByVal` instead.

Comment: ByVal didn't change anything - neither does just passing the variable on its own without specifying. Have updated the post to answer those questions Alex :)

Comment: Change Function to Sub and it may work. Or pass the argument as a string in parenthesis. Like this: `Call ShiftCompare("ShiftValue")`

Comment: Negative unfortunately, will keep reading the docs myself - thanks for the help so far guys!

Comment: @JohnHiggs - can you write `debug.print ShiftValue` in the line before calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the parameter when you are calling the function is not a string. Check the value of `ShiftValue` and try again. If you want to make sure it is a string, pass it like this `Call ShiftCompare("MyStringValue")`

---

The idea of the Function is that it is good that it returns a value.
Yours does not return. Change `Function` to `Sub`.

Comment: That's the one - the value was empty when being called. My initial for loop was picking up null or empty variable values and dealing with them on my last if statement, whereas when calling the function the value can't be null/empty. Will verify the value is not null/empty before calling that sub. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @JohnHiggs - just FYI - null and empty are different terms in VBA. Be careful for which one you are making the check.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vityata's answer above, consider a Select statement to avoid all those `ElseIf` statements. It runs faster.

```
Option Compare Text
Public Sub ShiftCompare(ByVal ShiftValue As String)
    Select Case True
        Case StrComp(ShiftValue, "am") = 0:
            Call IncAMs(AMs)   'this function increments the variable by 1.
            Call Inc(Counter)

        Case StrComp(ShiftValue, "pm") = 0:
            Call IncPMs(PMs)
            Call Inc(Counter)

        Case StrComp(ShiftValue, "days") = 0:
            Call IncDays(Days)
            Call Inc(Counter)

        Case StrComp(ShiftValue, "leave") = 0:
            Call IncLeave(Leave)
            Call Inc(Counter)

        Case Else:  'If the string doesn't compare to the above values tally it as unknown
            Call IncUnknown(Unknown)
            Call Inc(Counter)
    End Select
End Sub
```