# compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch, What am I missing?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm not understanding what the problem is.

I have the following code:

```
Public Sub SetupForm()
    Dim wbMain As Workbook
    Dim wsToner As Worksheet
    Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsToner = wbMain.Sheets("Toner")
    With DashboardForm
        'Parent nodes
        Dim Brands() As String
        Brands() = GetTonerBrand(wsToner)
```

The last line is calling the following function:

```
Private Function GetTonerBrand(wsSheet As Worksheet) As String
    Dim col, Counter
    Dim LastCol
    Counter = 0
    Dim LastRow
    Dim Brands() As String
    With wsSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim RowCount
        RowCount = LastRow
    End With
    Dim dict
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do While RowCount > 3
        If Not dict.exists(wsToner.Cells(RowCount, 2).Value) Then
            dict.Add wsToner.Cells(RowCount, 2).Value, 0
        End If
        RowCount = RowCount - 1
    Loop
    ReDim Brands(0 To dict.Count)
    Brands() = dict.keys()
    GetTonerBrand Brands
End Function
```

When I attempt to run this I get the error below:

> Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

I thought that if I update the type of the array and function then it would work.

So I changed the Function to String and the Brands() arrays as well were changed to String. Then I get an error:

> Compile error: Can't assign to array

in the `SetupForm` sub on the line `Brands() = GetTonerBrand(wsToner)`

Obviouly I'm missing something, I just don't see what it is.

**UPDATE**

I have seen this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239566/vba-byref-argument-type-mismatch) with a similar name, it isn't helpful.

Comment: Maybe the last line of GetTonerBrand should be `GetTonerBrand = Brands`.

Comment: The second to last line, it should be `GetTonerBrand = Brands`

Comment: `GetTonerBrand` says it returns a string but your returning a string array, so also change to `As String()`

Comment: You seem to be trying to assign a string to an array (Brands() = GetTonerBrand(wsToner)).  Brands() is an array, but your function is just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good points were made in the comments to your question, but none addressed the fact that VBA won't magically cast your dictionary keys, a `Variant` array, to a `String` array.

I suggest you modify your function to return a `Variant` array. In your calling code, you'd have to modify your declarartion:

```
'Parent nodes
Dim Brands() As Variant
```

In the code below, notice that superflous variables were eliminated, while remaining variables were declared with a suitable type. At the end, to return the value, the function's name is assigned the dictionary's keys.

```
Private Function GetTonerBrand(wsSheet As Worksheet) As Variant()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim tonerBrands As Object
    Dim tonerBrand As String

    With wsSheet
        row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    End With

    Set tonerBrands = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do While row > 3
        tonerBrand = CStr(wsToner.Cells(row, 2).Value)
        If Not tonerBrands.Exists(tonerBrand) Then
            tonerBrands.Add tonerBrand, 0
        End If
        row = row - 1
    Loop

    GetTonerBrand = tonerBrands.Keys()
End Function
```

A cool thing about variant arrays is that you can iterate through them using a variant-type variable, with a simple `For Each`.